# Right CSS rules containers for 4k screens

Tags: html, css

I need support to know a right or better way of handle a container for 4k screens or starting on a 1536px break point. What i want is fixed a width

[image]

the way that i implement to achive this is the next:
Markup:

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .global-bg {
      height: 800px;
      padding: 0 2rem;
      background-color: cadetblue;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      margin: 0;
      max-width: 1440px;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .content {
      color: white;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
      .global-bg {
        padding: 0 4rem;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1536px) {
      .content-wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="global-bg">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <p class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam beatae non voluptas, sequi nisi consequatur eius ut provident quam dolorem eligendi mollitia obcaecati sit et commodi asperiores aliquid voluptatum. Similique. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa hic eligendi obcaecati eveniet repellendus provident fugiat itaque deserunt aliquam accusantium quidem, voluptatibus consequatur consequuntur adipisci atque animi totam? Modi, esse? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat excepturi tenetur, numquam expedita dolores natus optio voluptatem odit, velit cumque fugit tempore amet vero incidunt deserunt nobis illum. Aperiam, reiciendis.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/armandopbringas/pen/MWoqpWa?editors=1100) i left a code pen with the code to you could see the implement more clear

So if anyone knows a right or better way to do this i will be following this post.

Comment: Hi! You have 'max-width: 1440px;' so no matter of the big resolution 1440px is the max width of the container. So what's the problem? According to the best practices you need to have maximum 60-80 characters per line to keep the text readable. If you're going to fill this container only with text, you could use columns for example.